# Using web deploy for Blazor app in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, blazor-server-side, webdeploy

I have a site written in Blazor Server hosted on some third-party server. The command

```ps
dotnet publish --configuration Release /p:PublishProfile=myPublishProfile.pubxml
```

successfully builds and updates my site on that server, meaning I can see real-time changes. Now, running that command in a GitHub Actions workflow like:

```yaml
- name: Publish to host
  run: dotnet publish --configuration Release /p:PublishProfile=myPublishProfile.pubxml
```

steps over this `Publish to host` step succesfully, but doesn't really update my site.

Again, in my publish profile I have correctly put `username`, `password` and `msdeployserviceurl` properties. It runs fine on my machine while putting that in command but has problems in GitHub Actions.

What am I doing wrong here?